# Should answer be removed, if it doesn't work?

Tags: discussion

I've flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458540/1991579) answer with "in need of moderator intervention", because even the author of that answer wrote:

> Sorry don't work !!

But a moderator declined this flag with message:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

So, how can I flag this answer to be deleted, because this answer is totally useless (even the author said it)?

Comment: Downvote the answer. and optionally ask the OP to delete or correct it.

Comment: @DavidPostill in my case the author of answer is unregistered user. Don't think that he will correct it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy it's actually the answer. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @Suvitruf: The linked duplicate goes to some pains to very carefully say that answers that do not work should ***under no circumstances be flagged as NAA*** just because they don't work.